# Returning the list of titles

Tags: haskell

Define a type LibraryItem representing an item the library loans to
patrons: either periodical or book. Periodicals have a catalogue number, a title, and a publication frequency. A publication frequency is either a number of days
or of months. Books have a catalogue number,
title, and author. Given only one book or periodical, return its title and catalogue number. Given a list of books and periodicals, return the list of titles and catalogue numbers.

```
data Libraryitem = Book {cataloguenumber1 :: Int , title1 :: String , author :: String}| Periodical {cataloguenumber2 :: Int, title2 ::String , publicationfrequency :: Publicationfrequency} deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
data Publicationfrequency = NumberofDays Int | NumberofMonths Int   deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

For returning a title when a book/periodical detail is given, the below code is working

```
titleR (Book _ titleR _ ) = titleR
titleR (Periodical _ titleR _ ) = titleR
```

I have two questions,

1)Is there any other way for returning the title and catalogue number of a single book using the title1 assignment I did while defining my data types?

2)How do I use recursion and perform this for a list of items

My try for recursion is below

```
titlen1 [] = []
titlen1 (x:xs) = if x == (Book  _ title1 _)
                 then title1 : title1 xs
```

Although, I would prefer using title1 which I used in my definition. I am also aware that this code is not sufficient to perform the task.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are misunderstanding how pattern-matching works. Check [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) for more info on how pattern-matching works in Haskell.

> 1) Is there any other way for returning the title and catalogue number
>   of a single book using the title1 assignment I did while defining my
>   data types?

Yes you can, but the return type will be different. The simplest way is to return a tuple.

```
titleR' :: LibraryItem -> (String, Int)
titleR' (Book catNumber titleR _) = (titleR, catNumber)
titleR' (Periodical catNumber titleR _) = (titleR, catNumber)
```

> 2) How do I use recursion and perform this for a list of items?

Following is the solution using plain recursion.

```
titles :: [LibraryItem] -> [String]
titles [] = []
titles ((Book _ t _):xs) = t : titles xs
titles ((Periodical _ t _):xs) = t : titles xs
```

Or you can use map function (reusing our previous `titleR'` function)

```
titles :: [LibraryItem] -> [(String, Int)]
titles xs = map titleR' xs
```